# ImportError from non-standard Python even though module exists

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos6, python-2.6

We have a setup based on CentOS 6.4 but with Python 2.7 (due to historical reasons). Note that CentOS 6 [brings](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/) Python 2.6. Python 2.7 has been compiled from a Fedora 20 SRPM. In addition, to make it possible to freely use Python RPMs from CentOS 6 along with the 2.7 interpreter, we have created a `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setup.pth` file with the contents:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

Things used to work fine till the need to use `protobuf-python-2.3.0-9.el6.x86_64` arose. This RPM has been downloaded from the EPEL repo and is available: [here](http://epel.mirror.net.in/epel/6/x86_64/protobuf-python-2.3.0-9.el6.x86_64.rpm).

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7.4 (default, Mar 17 2015, 00:48:39) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import google.protobuf
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf
```

One thing that could be helpful is that the import error does not come with Python 2.6:

```
$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import google.protobuf
```

This error does not come with other import statements (e.g. `import pip.vcs`). It is somehow related to `protobuf-python`. What could be the reason? Any insight will be appreciated.

EDIT: The `protobuf-python` RPM installs files into `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/google/protobuf` and the the 2.7 interpreter's `sys.path` is:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7 -c 'import sys; print sys.path' | sed -e 's/,/\n/g'
[''
 '/usr/lib64/python27.zip'
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7'
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2'
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk'
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old'
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload'
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages'
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages'
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
```

Comment: Where is that package located, and is its location on the 2.7 `sys.path`?

Comment: And if you run `python -v` and try to import it?

Comment: @BrenBarn I have edited the question clarifying that the 2.7's `sys.path` includes the module's directory. There is one thing that might be of significance: The `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/google` directory does not contain any `__init__.py` file. It only has a `protobuf` sub-directory. The contents are exactly as per the EPEL RPM. Nothing has been modified here.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks for the tip. I tried loading the `google.protobuf` module from both Python 2.6 and 2.7 using the `-v` switch. It turns out that the 2.6 interpreter searches for `__init__.so`, `__init__module.so` and `__init__.py` in the `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/` directory while the 2.7 one searches for `google.so`, `googlemodule.so` and `google.py` in the `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/` directory, none of which exist. The 2.6 interpreter succeeds because `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/__init__.pyc` gets found.

Comment: I have been able to avoid the import error by doing `touch /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/google/__init__.py `. I am trying to find why this is required for 2.7 and and not for 2.6.